# Installing MonoTouch - ibtool not found error

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

[edit]

Found the solution. Reinstall EVERYTHING - xcode, mono, monodevelop and monotouch. Now it works. yay.

[/edit]

I've had Xcode (3.2.1 - SnowLeopard, iphone 3.1.3) installed for a while, and I can run and build apps on it fine.

I installed MonoTouch, as I want to leverage the 8+ years of .NET skills I have :)

So I installed:

- **Mono**: MonoFramework-2.6.1_1.macos10.novell.x86
- **MonoTouch**: monotouch-eval-1.5.0
- **MonoDevelop**: MonoDevelop-2.2.1-r152508 (was 2.2.1,
  but when I started it up, it said
  there was an update, which I installed - thats the update version)

If I make a new project and build it, I get any of the following errors:

- Build failed. Object reference not
  set to the instance of an object.
- Build failed: ibtool not found (btw,
  it's in /Developer/usr/bin/ibtool) or
  a similar one to the second one if I
  use the older (2.2.1 released)
  version of MonoTouch.

I can't find any debug info anywhere. I could reinstall XCode/iPhone SDK, but as it already is installed and works (and no, this isn't a SL upgrade), it doesn't make sense.

Anyone got any ideas? I SO want to use MonoTouch - Obj-C drives me up the wall! Console apps (mono ones) work fine.

Mac OS X 10.6.2, Macbook Pro, clean install with old settings moved over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting to make the answer to the question more obvious on the list, the solution was:

The "ibtool" not found means that MonoTouch/MonoDevelop can not find your XCode installation.   Chances are, you did not install the XCode SDK.   Sometimes upgrades break Apple's SDK, so you need to reinstall Apple's SDK.

Comment: Thanks Miguel - but in this case, no. I had the SDK installed, and it worked perfectly (to the point of developing, deploying and putting an app in the app store).

In the end, I had to reinstall the SDK, mono, monotouch and monodevelop, which fixed it. I suspect that whereever MD is looking for the path to IBTOOL (I assume you look in a plist somewhere, which then points to the folder? which was, in this case, in the default - /Developer/usr/bin I think), doesn't get moved over in a migration between machines, which I had done.

Thanks for the reply tho. :)

Comment: BTW, marking this as the answer, as in most cases it is! in this case, "install the SDK" is not the right answer, "REinstall the SDK" is :)